# Ansible regex_findall is not giving expected results with negative search

Tags: ansible, python-regex

My ansible negative regex is returning everything

So I'm getting results of dns names from JSON, of which I'm trying to sort to create an automated ansible inventory.
I have servers with naming schemes such as:

```
abc02vsomeserver01.subdomain1.domain.gov
abc02someserver01.subdomain1.domain.gov
xyz03votherserver11.subdomain2.domain.gov
wyz03otherserver11.subdomain2.domain.gov
qrsmainserver02.maindomain.domain.gov
```

I'm getting the "v" servers divided out by environment, then I want to create a catchall group that is not the "v" servers
So! I'm attempting to do:

```
{{ jsonOutput | json_query('json.response.results[].dnsName') | regex_findall('(?![a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}v)^.*', multiline=true) }}
```

Which does seem to work when I plug it into https://pythex.org.
But ansible is returning everything instead...
What the heck am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because that `json_query` emits a `list[str]` which when fed directly into `regex_findall` doesn't become a newline delimited string, it becomes the same as `str(["alpha", "beta"])` (e.g. `['alpha', 'beta']`) and then the multiline regex fails to do what you are expecting

There are, as with many things in life, a few ways to fix that. One is to just feed the results into `|join("\n")` and then you're likely back where you thought you were to begin with:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ jsonOutput | json_query('json.response.results[].dnsName') | join('\n') | regex_findall('(?![a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}v)^.*', multiline=true) }}"
```

The other is to acknowledge that it's a `list[str]` and use the `| select("match", ...)` filter to only allow though items that match:

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ response | json_query('results[].dnsName')
          | select('match', '(?![a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}v)^.*')
          | list }}
      vars:
        response:
          results:
          - dnsName: abc02vsomeserver01.subdomain1.domain.gov
          - dnsName: abc02someserver01.subdomain1.domain.gov
          - dnsName: xyz03votherserver11.subdomain2.domain.gov
          - dnsName: wyz03otherserver11.subdomain2.domain.gov
          - dnsName: qrsmainserver02.maindomain.domain.gov
```

similarly produces:

```json
    "msg": [
        "abc02someserver01.subdomain1.domain.gov",
        "wyz03otherserver11.subdomain2.domain.gov",
        "qrsmainserver02.maindomain.domain.gov"
    ]
```

I would guess it's personal preference which style works best in your playbook

Comment: This is great! Thank you!!! That lil join('\n') did the trick! Perfect!!!!